# 'Hide Div when mouse is clicked outside the Div' All attempts not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set my code to hide divs when the background or other div is clicked. I have four buttons and when one is active and another is clicked, the active element should close and the other opens. However, with my code the active element hides when I move the mouse away from it. I need it to stay put until I click the background. I have tried different options, the last of which is the '.mouseout'. Please see my code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="architecture">
  <object class="archsvg" type="image/svg+xml" data="architecture-icon.svg" width="260px" height="288.14px">
         </object>
  <a href="architecture.html">
    <div class="arch">
      <p class="to-architecture">Continue to 9haus Architecture</p>
      <hr class="aline" />
    </div>
  </a>
  <button class="closea">x</button>
</div>

<script>
  (function($) {
    $("#a").click(function() {
      $(".architecture").toggle('slide', {
        direction: 'right'
      }, 500);
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>

<script>
  (function($) {
    $('.closea').click(function() {
      $('.architecture').hide('slide', {
        direction: 'right'
      }, 500);
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>

<script>
  (function($) {
    $(':not(.architecture)').mouseout(function() {
      $('.architecture').hide('slide', {
        direction: 'right'
      }, 500);
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the minimal version of the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lws53qyw/1/

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example if you want us to help

Comment: can you please create a snippet or a fiddle, then we can see the code running instead of just read it?

Comment: How do I do any of those? Still finding my way around stackoverflow

Comment: I have updated the code to show a minimal version of the problem.

Comment: jsfiddle now included

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a "Stack Snippet" to show the code running here on Stack Overflow. I'm not sure that I've captured what you're trying to do, since moving the mouse anywhere in the result hides the menu...

Comment: Cheers for that  @MikeMcCaughan. Im trying to make the menu stay as it is until I click the background or another menu. Right now, moving the mouse away from the trigger button is enough to close the div; no click necessary. I don't want that.